# Tokenize and get arbitrary number token using regex

Tags: regex

I am not very familiar with regular expressions and ran into a problem which is beyond me.
I would like help with coming up with an expression which tokenizes a string and then gets me arbitrary tokens counting from the end.

For example, I would like to get `P037-077` from the following string

`http://www.wayfair.com/George-Kovacs-by-Minka-Bling-Bling-1-Light-Wall-Sconce-P037-077-GKV1032.html`

So, I want the second and third last token with the delimiter being "-".

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Well, the tool I'm using, diffbot,  takes regex as an input and it uses Java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of regex:

```
-([^-]*-[^-]*)-[^-]*$
```

But you probably don't really need a regex to do this. Just split the string on `-` and get the items you want. With Ruby: (implement it on whatever language you are using)

```
str = "http://www.wayfair.com/George-Kovacs-by-Minka-Bling-Bling-1-Light-Wall-Sconce-P037-077-GKV1032.html"
str.split("-")[-3..-2]
#=> ["P037", "077"]
```

Comment: Well, the tool I'm using, diffbot, only  takes regex as an input and it uses Java syntax.